# MYSQL two updates with AND BETWEEN conditions

Tags: mysql

how can i make the below update query in one phrase? thanks.

```
UPDATE tableA SET ColumnA = 1  WHERE id_tableA = 10000 AND (date_tableA BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-30');

UPDATE tableB SET ColumnB = 1  WHERE id_tableB = 10000 AND (date_tableB BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-30');
```

i tried the below code but it just won't update any thing:

```
UPDATE tableA AS a, tableB AS b
SET a.ColumnA = 1, b.Column = 1
WHERE a.id = 10000 AND b.id = 10000 AND
((a.date_tableA BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-30') OR
(b.date_tableB BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-30'))
```

the above code works well with out the date between conditions.

Comment: Are you talking about a transaction?

Comment: Hi, I just tried to use comma, but everything runs well until it comes to the date between condition. When I add a date between condition, it updates nothings.

Comment: You mean update both tables in one query?  I don't think you can do that, but using a transaction will give you what I assume you are looking for.  Transactions will not update indexes until it's committed.  See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html

Comment: `01-06-2021` is not a date, it's the number `-2026`.  You need to use a string `'01-06-2021'`.

Comment: oh I think transaction will work, lemme try

Comment: I don't think you can combine both statements as they are 2 different tables. BTW why did you leave quotes in dates in second query.

Comment: Hi Rocket Hazmat, that was just a typo, it got a ' in my code, but the result just won't update anything with out any error pop up.

Comment: I wonder if `'31-06-2021'` is a valid date.  Should it be `'2021-06-31'`?  Should `'01-06-2021'` also be changed to `'2021-06-01'`?  You are looking at the month of `June, 2021` right?

Comment: Rocket Hazmat, the update works well when i break it to 2 phrases, but when i use comma to combine them it updates nothing

Comment: @AnthonyTam Can you explain *why* you are trying to combine the queries?  What problem are you trying to solve?  Is there any relation between `tableA` and `tableB`?  If not, then joining them isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

If `date_tableA` and `date_tableB` are `DATE` fields, then you need to filter on then using the correct format.

MySQL expects dates to be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html

```
UPDATE tableA SET ColumnA = 1
WHERE id_tableA = 10000 AND (date_tableA BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-30');

UPDATE tableB SET ColumnB = 1
WHERE id_tableB = 10000 AND (date_tableB BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-30');
```

<sub>Note: June has 30 days, not 31.</sub>

---

If you want combine the, you can use `UPDATE` with `JOIN`.

```
UPDATE tableA, tableB
JOIN tableB ON id_tableA = id_tableB
SET tableA = 1, tableB = 1
WHERE id_tableA = 10000
AND (date_tableA BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-30')
AND (date_tableB BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-30');
```

This could work if there is an actual *relation* between `tableA` and `tableB`.  If they are unrelated tables, then I wouldn't suggest a `JOIN`.

You could also use a transaction so that the indexes aren't updated until after all updates are done.

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE tableA SET ColumnA = 1
WHERE id_tableA = 10000 AND (date_tableA BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-30');

UPDATE tableB SET ColumnB = 1
WHERE id_tableB = 10000 AND (date_tableB BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-30');

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Hi Rocket, the real code has no such problem, and it was just a typo.

Comment: @AnthonyTam Could the issue be that June 31st doesn't exist? :-P

Comment: typo again =P sorry, i set the begin date as the first day of the month and the end date as today

Comment: i think i will use transaction instead, thanks!